# Why does GitZilla's update hook throws an error message on push?

Tags: git, bugzilla, pybugz

Configured everything as stated on the Gitzilla website.

My git repo is working fine for weeks now... Bugzilla is working fine also...

After ending the config of Gitzilla, i branched and tested to see if i could push and it gets logged... it gives me this error:

```
Counting objects: 57, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (42/42), done.
Writing objects: 100% (54/54), 5.59 KiB, done.
Total 54 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "hooks/update", line 8, in <module>
remote:     load_entry_point('gitzilla==2.0', 'console_scripts', 'gitzilla-update')()
remote:   File "build/bdist.freebsd-8.2-RELEASE-amd64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
remote:   File "build/bdist.freebsd-8.2-RELEASE-amd64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
remote:   File "build/bdist.freebsd-8.2-RELEASE-amd64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
remote:   File "build/bdist.freebsd-8.2-RELEASE-amd64/egg/gitzilla/hookscripts.py", line 11, in <module>
remote:   File "build/bdist.freebsd-8.2-RELEASE-amd64/egg/gitzilla/hooks.py", line 9, in <module>
remote:   File "build/bdist.freebsd-8.2-RELEASE-amd64/egg/gitzilla/utils.py", line 10, in <module>
remote: ImportError: No module named bugz.bugzilla
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/roger/gitzilla
To ssh://git@git.some.net/usr/local/git/some.git
 ! [remote rejected] roger/gitzilla -> roger/gitzilla (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@git.some.net/usr/local/git/some.git'
```

Comment: Silly question, but does the server have the bugz.bugzilla python module installed?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install pybugz - I had exactly the same issue

git repo is here
https://github.com/williamh/pybugz

See requirements
Requirements
............

To install and run GitZilla, you need:

- Python (tested with 2.6.4, should work with >=2.5)
- pybugz (tested with 0.8.0)